# c++ thread передача enum

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Вот кусок кода, хочу его запустить отдельным потоком

```
if (keyLength == 1024)
            rsa.generateKeys(RSA::RSA_1024);
        else if (keyLength == 2048)
            rsa.generateKeys(RSA::RSA_2048);
```

Ну вот написал так:

```
if (keyLength == 1024)
            std::thread(rsa.generateKeys, RSA::RSA_1024).join();
        else if (keyLength == 2048)
            std::thread(rsa.generateKeys, RSA::RSA_2048).join();
```

Пытаюсь скомпилить, нифига не выходит. Вылезает куча ошибок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прототип функции:

```
enum KeyLength {RSA_1024 = 512, RSA_2048 = 1024};
void generateKeys(KeyLength keyLength = RSA_2048);
```

UPDATE:

```
if (keyLength == 1024)
            std::thread(&RSA::generateKeys, &rsa, RSA::RSA_1024).join();
        else if (keyLength == 2048)
            std::thread(&RSA::generateKeys, &rsa, RSA::RSA_2048).join();
```

Вроде заработало

Comment: @Abyx угадали. Ну так и что? Неправильно передал функцию?

Comment: Только вот смысла в такой передаче - никакого. `std::thread(&RSA::generateKeys, &rsa, RSA::RSA_1024).join();` - ваш основной поток тратит силы и время на запуск нового, после чего останавливается и ждет, пока ваш новый поток сделает свою работу... Результат - замедление работы программы :(

Comment: @Harry у меня там выше создается прогрессБар, но полоска почему то не бегает, почему? Если основной поток дожидается, он же может крутить эту чертову полоску прогрессБара.

Comment: Основной поток у вас заблокирован, он просто остановился и ждет.

Answer (score 1):

При передаче указателя на нестатическую функцию-член, нужно вторым аргументом передавать указатель на класс, членом которого она является, в данном случае, this. Это относится к большинству функций std, которым можно передать функциональный объект в качестве аргумента (обычно в таких случаях аргументы интерпретируются как в std::bind).